# Add Custom HTTP Header to Request sent by BlazeDS and AMF

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, blazeds, amf

in our application we have a flex Client, this client uses BlazeDS and AMF to excute operation, 
Is there a way to add a custom Http header to the request sent from the AMF so i can read in our Filter in Java server Side

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom header with anything you like in it, like this:

```
headers = [
        new URLRequestHeader("contentType", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
        new URLRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "en_US"),
        new URLRequestHeader("X-Authorization", "Bearer " + API_KEY)
    ];
```

Then use it like:

```
 var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(API_URL);
    urlReq.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
    urlReq.requestHeaders = headers;
var _jsonLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    _jsonLoader.load(urlReq);
```